# Wine 1.7.38 doesn't update to latest beta

Tags: 14.04, updates, wine

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 trusty x64. Altough I've added the Wine repo, made sure it's selected (even the sources branch), then tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install wine1.7
sudo apt-get install wine
```

But it said there's nothing to update. Other Ubuntu updates show up from time to time, so updating works in general.

Also, when I click "install latest wine 1.7 beta" on  winehq.org --> download --> ubuntu - it does redirect me to wine 1.7.38 in the Ubuntu Software Center, which actually isn't the most recent.

I want to update so I can provide test-data on https://appdb.winehq.org/, I need the latest beta for it.

What am i doing wrong?

***Edit:***
I guess i found out myself: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/wine/vivid/main/base/wine1.7
There is no newer version on ubuntu, it seems the repo is out of date, i'll try to contact the maintainer or someone at wine.

(as of 2.June '15, there is no newer wine than 1.7.38 in the ubuntu repo)

Sorry for opening a thread;)

(and for not being able to post everything as link due to low reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wine packages in the ppa they list only goes to 1.7.38. I am running 1.7.44, which is the latest by using the Wine Staging stuff.

http://www.wine-staging.com/

I followed the instructions from the following link & am running 1.7.44 on 15.04, but I was running it on 14.10 earlier today until my hard drive decided to die :)

https://github.com/wine-compholio/wine-staging/wiki/Installation#-ubuntulinux-mint

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-staging wine-staging-compat
```

Comment: @hirsch did that work out for you?

Comment: yes, indeed. atm winecfg and winetricks seem notto be present in the unity menu. However, command line execution works fine, confirms 1.7.44.